# Hibernate Composite Primary Key with partial ManyToOne cannot be inserted

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

**Goal**

I want to insert an Entity with its relations (consolidated PK which has an FK) using only one call to a @Repository-Interface.

standart Entity:

```
@Entity
class EntityA {
  @Id
  private String id;                // this is provided and must not be generated
}
```

Entity with both relations:

```
@Entity
public class EntityB implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String entityAId;         // foreign key on EntityA ID

  @OneToOne                         // EntityA can be inserted with EntityB
  @MapsId                           // maps EntityA's ID to the field entityAId
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn             // joines to primary key column (instead of @JoinClumn)
  private EntityA entityA;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.entityB")  // bidirectional mapping should assure insertability of EntityC from EntityB
  private List<EntityC> entityCList;
}
```

Entity with consolidated primary key, where one part is a foreign key:

```
@Entity
public class EntityC implements Serializable {
  @EmbeddedId
  EntityCId id;

  @Embeddable
  public static class EntityCId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private EntityB entityB;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer number;
  }
}
```

EntityBRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface EntityBRepository extends
  ListCrudRepository<EntityB, EntityA>,
  PagingAndSortingRepository<EntityB, EntityA> {
}
```

Call to Interface Method (the insert):

```
entityBRepo.save(
  EntityB.builder()
    .entityA(
       EntityA.builder()
         .id("abcd")
       .build()
    )
    .entityCList(List.of(
       EntityC.builder()
         .entityCId(new EntityC.EntityCId())
       .build()
    )
  .build()
);
```

**Expectation**

- my insert should work
- all of my three tables should be filled, each with one entry
- all three SQL statements should be printed accordingly

**Result**

```
[main] org.hibernate.SQL: insert into entity_a (id) values (?)
[main] org.hibernate.SQL: insert into entity_b (entity_a_id) values (?)
```

- only two SQL statements are generated (accordingly to log)
- only two inserts happened on the database
- no error message or anything similar